# Git LFS on Windows: cannot revert a file

Tags: git, git-lfs

If I delete from my Git repo a file that is stored on LFS, commit and then try to rebase my branch on the master, Git will see this file as modified during the rebase. If I revert the file doing `git checkout -- mybigfile`
then `git status` will still list this file as modified and I am kind of stuck. The only thing I can do is to commit the file and pray I will not have to rebase until my commits are pushed.

My git configuration is:

```
core.autocrlf=true
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
```

and my version is `2.17.1.windows.2`.

How do you force Git to really revert a file stored on LFS or stop Git from seeing the file as modified ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the workaround I found, inspired by this [bug report](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1726):

```
cp /dev/null .gitattributes
git checkout -- mybigfile
git checkout -- .gitattributes
```